# How to resolve IP non uniqueness when I'm capturing it in my application for a specific purpose

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

In my application I've been using the client's IP address to allow him to access some functionality in a specific page. I'll be saving the client side IP in DB and match the request IP with it and do the validation for accesing that functionality.

However, my application is up and running in production. Earlier my client was on the same network as my organization was, so the IP was constant. 
While providing the same service to other client they wern't in our organization network, so he has a public IP. His ip would change and this needs to be updated in db regularyly in db.

How to handle this now? Any alternative to handle this situation without changing the application logic and changing something at the network Side.

Comment: Did you consider that an IP addresses can change when the user's ISP feels like it? Or that the user can use a wifi hotspot or VPN, causing their IP to change as well? This reeks of an XY problem.

Comment: You should not use IP addresses for authentication. You should have a login process, either token based (e.g. OAuth2) or using cookies or something. You can potentially consider that someone's token/session is invalid if their IP changes, but you can't use IP as the only way of working out who someone is.

Comment: By the way, if it isn't for authentication, this is the kind of situation where cookies are normally used.

Comment: There are scenario's where this is valid; for example; only allow access to a page from a known server, or localhost, or country. Nevertheless, I agree with CodeCaster we need more info here. Btw; the logic to handle this can be the same, DHCP may alter IP's just as ISP's do.

Comment: So why is it a problem that ip is public and not private?

Comment: What happens if multiple people share the same PC, so may have the same IP address?

Comment: @john Hi john. This logic is not used for authentication. We have everyhitg else which take cares of that. This is for a different implementation inside the project where we are checking that the request coming id the registered ip and we allow him use Cisco dialer services. There is a mapping of configuration on basis of the request ip which fetches the dialer config.

Comment: Initially this application was built for the clients of the same organization so the ip config logic has been used. It can be done in various other ways but since it is a production issue, so I need to see something can be fixed using the same logic.

Comment: @Evk It is a problem beacuse I cant go and change the ip address each and every time it changes, in the DB. A solution has to be thought of making this dynamic instead of a static solution.

Comment: But don't you have other means to check if the user is allowed to use those services? Is it not `(hasPermission && ipMatches)`? And by the same token, is the config not `user,ip`?